# Como configurar JSF no Eclipse JEE?

Tags: java-ee, jsf, jsf-2.2

Estou iniciando meus estudos em JSF, como posso configurar meu ambiente para iniciar com JSF no Eclipse JEE? O que eu preciso instalar de complemento?

Comment: Você pode seguir esse tutorial: http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/creating-jsf2-hello-world-application-in-eclipse/

Comment: Muito obrigado @Rafael!

Comment: Essa dá caelum é muito boa para iniciantes. http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/